# Rails, Nested Resources, Tracking activity on the parent w/o having to query the child

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Given two models like so:

```
Photo has_many comments
Comment belongs_to photo
```

I'd like to be able to obtain a list of photos ordered by most recently commented. I supposed I could run a query across the two tables but that seems to be very intensive, no?

Is there a way I can add a field to Photo, last_activity, and then anytime a comment that belongs to a photo is created, automatically have that last_activity field updated?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a after_created filter in you Comment model and there update last_activity of the photo it belongs to with the current time.